# How fix dialog windows size in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

Dialog popup with bad size
[image: Dialog popup with bad size]

Why popup is so small? After manual resize windows still the same size...

Comment: what is the shell theme you are using?

Comment: Default.I just change it to Pop Dark - result the same...

Comment: is it happening only with telegram app?

Comment: Yes, I guess it is only telegram issue...

Comment: It's not about Telegram. Its about snap. Anything installed with snap are kind of in sandbox so they ask permissions like these.

Comment: Where did you get `Pop Dark` from?